# How to catch third party console log using log4j

Tags: java, web-services, logging, console, log4j

I'm using log4j for logging actions in my application. I use following file appender:

```
 private FileAppender getFileAppender(String name) {
  PatternLayout layout = new PatternLayout("%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %t %c{1}:%M:%L - %m%n");
  StringBuilder filePath = new StringBuilder();
  filePath.append("logs/")
        .append(name)
        .append(".log");
  FileAppender fileAppender = null;

  try {
     File file = new File(filePath.toString());
     file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
     file.createNewFile();

     fileAppender = new FileAppender(layout, filePath.toString(), true);
     fileAppender.setName("FileAppender");
     fileAppender.setAppend(true);
  } catch (IOException e) {
     LogWrapper.LOG.get(this.getClass().getSimpleName()).trace(e);
  }

  return fileAppender;
  }
```

My application uses third party, what logs web services calls into console. Then I run application I see those logs in my console in Intellij Idea, but not on the  generated log file.

How to redirect those logs into the file, generated by File Appender?

*Update*
The answer is correct, but there is one more third party what use logback with Console Appender, properties looks like:

```
<configuration status="OFF">
<appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
        </pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>
<root level="WARN">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
</root>
```

Because of this catching console output stacks. How could I catch and re-write Logback properties and make it log to file or disable logs at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this to log STDOUT as INFO and STDERR as WARNING for example:

```
final Logger myLog4jLogger = Logger.getLogger(getClass());

System.setOut(new PrintStream(new ByteArrayOutputStream() {
    @Override
    public synchronized void write(byte[] pB, int pOff, int pLen) {
        super.write(pB, pOff, pLen);
        myLog4jLogger.info(toString());
        reset();
    }
}));

System.setErr(new PrintStream(new ByteArrayOutputStream() {
    @Override
    public synchronized void write(byte[] pB, int pOff, int pLen) {
        super.write(pB, pOff, pLen);
        myLog4jLogger.warn(toString());
        reset();
    }
}));
```

Do this only once after Log4j initialization and before calling your third party tool.
Be careful, it means that the STDOUT and STDERR of your process will be redirected to your logs, so all the text sent to STDOUT/STDERR by your process will go to logs, including your own `"System.out.println()"`.

Also, using this, you may want to avoid logging to the console, because I'm not sure what will happen if you log to the console and that the console is redirected to the logs... (endless loop? stack overflow? OutOfMemoryError?)

Concerning the third party that uses Logback, you can send its logs to a file instead of STDOUT by adding this to its config file:

```
<appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
   <file>myApp.log</file>

   <encoder>
     <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
   </encoder>
</appender>
```

And by replacing:

```
<appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
```

...with:

```
<appender-ref ref="FILE" />
```

Comment: Looks like one of my other third party logs into console, because solution works perfect if I run tests using testng (without external reporter), but then I run suite using gradle it just stacks. Is it possible to retrieve log properties of third party and rewrite so it do not log into console, or something like this? Or I'm not right in this assumption at all?

Comment: If this third party is using a proper logging library (Log4j 1/2, Logback, JUL, ...), it should be possible by editing its log configuration file before it loads this config file. But if this third party uses hard-coded "System.out.println()", you are stuck.

Comment: could you please advice how to catch logs property of such third party and adjust it?

Comment: I have figured out that third party used logback. Will update question with details

Comment: Since your current question deals with Log4j, you may ask a new question instead of updating this one (third-party using Logback). Feel free to post a link to this new question here if you want me to have a look ;-)

Comment: Well, ignore my last comment, it should not be a big deal, I've updated my answer as well :)